# simple_html_dom not loading all elements

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am doing data scrapping on a website, where I'm trying to get all product URL's from a category page. I am not sure why simple_html_dom isn't returning the product URLs from the category page. Here is my PHP code.

```
// Require simplehtmldom
require_once 'includes/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php';
// Category page URL
$srcurl = 'http://www.lastcall.com/Hers/Womens-Apparel/Dresses/Cocktail/cat11210008_cat5900001_cat6150001/c.cat#userConstrainedResults=true&refinements=&page=1&pageSize=120&sort=&definitionPath=/nm/commerce/pagedef_rwd/template/EndecaDriven&locationInput=&radiusInput=100&onlineOnly=&allStoresInput=false&rwd=true&catalogId=cat11210008';

$html = file_get_html($srcurl); // get DOM from URL or file
```

The file_get_html wasn't displaying any HTML element from "lastcall" (was working fine for other website URLs). So, I used PHPs CURL like this,

```
// Line 1 to 4 same
// $html = file_get_html($srcurl); // get DOM from URL or file
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $srcurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $srcurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html = new simple_html_dom(); // Create a DOM object
$html->load($str); // Load HTML from a string

echo $html; // Disply data on test page
```

After using CURL I am getting only the header and footer data from the above URL but the page is not displaying products block, from where I can actually extract all the products link. I just need help with displaying the products block, later I can implement match case to get the product links. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ankur

Comment: looks like the content of the website ist getting loaded via ajax... so the curl only gets the blank page without the content that got server asynchronously

Comment: Hello FalcoB, thanks for the comment. Is there any PHP function, that will get the ajax content?